# Traverse through JSON and create React components

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, traversal

How can I traverse through my data structure and create React components?

```
{
  component: "View",
  attributes: {
    id: 'main'
  },
  child: [
    {
      component: "Text",
      content: "Hello World!"
    },
    {
      component: "Link",
      attributes: {
        href: "#"
      },
      child: [
        {
          component: "Text",
          content: "Click me!"
        }
      ]
    }
  ] 
}
```

Would output:

```
<View>
  <Text>Hello World!</Text>
  <Link>Click me!</Link>
</View>
```

How can I dynamically achieve this where it works regardless of the number of nested components?

I am able to make the top level component, but traversing through the `child` elements is where I hit a brick wall.

Comment: What did you try, do you have code to show us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function that calls itself.

**Sample**

```
parseComponents = (data, key) => {
  if (key === undefined || key === null) key = 0;
  let Component = null;
  switch(data.component) {
    case 'View': 
      Component = View;
      break;
    case 'Text':
      Component = Text;
      break;
    case 'Link':
      Component = Link;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  if (Component === null) return Component;

  return (
    <Component key={`${data.component}-${index}`} {...data.attributes}>
      {data.child.map((c, index) => this.parseComponents(c, index))}
    </Component>
  )
}
```

Comment: Would this support, for instance 10 levels of nested components?

Comment: @Dan yes it would since it calls the function as long as there is a child array in that component

Comment: Dude, absolute legend!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like sample below:
Let's say your JSON is stored in `const json`.

```
getComponent = (json) => {
if (json.component) {
  let children;
  if (json.children) {
     children = json.children.map(child => this.getComponentEquivalent(child));
  }

  let Container= this.getComponentEquivalent(json);

  return (<Container>{children}</Container>); // as this will return a component you can directly put this in render.
 }
};
```

then you may have a function that you could get equivalent component.

```
getComponentEquivalent = (object) => {
    switch(object.component) {
      case "Text":
          return <Text>{object.content}</Text>
      case "Link"":
          return <Link>{object.content}</Link>
      //......./
      default:
           //..../
    }
};
```